# Is it possible to embed another exe in my program using C++?

Tags: c++

I am mostly a .Net guy and the transition from VB.Net to C++ has been quite painful.

Anyway, just like in Visual Studio, we can add resources to our program, is it possible to add an exe as a resource to my C++ program which will extract itself from my exe and run only if needed?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but since it can be put to pernicious use, I'm not sure anyone ought to answer this.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?  Why do you want to embed a program in a program?  As @Bathsheba said, this comes off as a way to circumvent failsafes.  There may be a better, supported, and expected way to accomplish what you're actually after.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your input guys. :)

Comment: Embedding an exe as a resource is _not_ any evil, pernicious thing that AVs have never seen before... In fact, it is a very common thing to do. UPX, for example, not only includes an exe, it _compresses_ it. LOL.

Comment: I think it would be good to answer the "What are you actually trying to do?" question.  I have "embedded" python and other things within C++ when I wanted to allow customization.  Any good answer would depend on the end goal.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just embed its binary data as an array of whatever fundamental type you want, perhaps in a header -- unsigned char, int, whatever -- write it to disk on execution of your parent application, then call it as a child process.

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, it seems a bit silly and like there are other approaches you can take. It might also trigger some antivirus heuristics, as this is a common way viruses propagate.

If you *do* do this, you'll also probably want to store it as a compressed byte/int array to save space, and then decompress it on the fly. Or at least Base-85 to keep your header file smaller.